# I have a list of xpaths, how can I open each one of them in a different tab?

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome

Basically, I have a website where I need to open several tabs and do something in each one of them. How can I do it using Python + Selenium and Chrome?
This is the code I have:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import os
import time
import pyautogui
option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_prefs = {}
option.experimental_options["prefs"] = chrome_prefs
chrome_prefs["profile.default_content_settings"] = {"images": 2}
chrome_prefs["profile.managed_default_content_settings"] = {"images": 2}
chrome_prefs["profile.default_content_settings"] = { "popups": 2 }
option.add_argument("--disable-notifications")


    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=option)
    driver.get('https://www.spiritfanfiction.com/login')
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='Usuario']").send_keys("breakfast")
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@title='Senha']").send_keys("302290679")
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='btn btn-primary']").send_keys("302290679")
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='btn btn-primary']").click()

#this opens the page I need to get all the xpaths from 
    LinkDoPerfil = driver.get("https://www.spiritfanfiction.com/recentes?pagina=1000")

#this is the xpath I need to open in each tab
    transactionElements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@class='usuario usuarioPopupTrigger link']")

#this is the part I have no idea what I'm doing lol. But it was supposed to open all the xpaths in a different tab.      
    for element in transactionElements:
            ActionChains(driver) \
                .key_down(Keys.CONTROL) \
                .click(element) \
                .key_up(Keys.CONTROL) \
                .perform()

#this switches to the latest opened tab, which is the final xpath I got from the page.
    driver.switch_to_window(driver.window_handles[-1])
    try:
            driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@class="fa fa-eye"]').click()
    except:
            browser.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 'w')
```

Could somebody please tell me what is wrong? It was working before but I messed it up and now it's not. Nothing happens after:

```
LinkDoPerfil = driver.get("https://www.spiritfanfiction.com/recentes?pagina=1000")
```

Comment: Can't reproduce this issue. getting an error ```Senha Invalida!```

Comment: Because I can't put my password here for everyone to see.

Comment: So how can we reproduce this issue

Comment: I just need to open some xpaths, each one in a different tab.

Comment: we don't understand that language, so it will be difficult to browse through that website to find what you are searching for

Comment: It will be better if you can guide each and every step

Comment: ok, the code is working with a different account. It's working for you to try. sorry about it. I'll make the guide.

Comment: So its working. Should I close this issue?

Comment: noooo, sorry. I mean I added a different account for everyone to try. It's working for you to try, there is no login error anymore.

Comment: Tell me one thing is it the full code file. The entire code that you are using to scrape. Right??

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm a total beginner to Python. What do you mean by "scrape"?

Comment: it is like the extraction of data from the web page

Comment: I am able to open each and every page from the link, which is stored in your transactionelements. Is there anything more you want

Comment: oooooh, after https://www.spiritfanfiction.com/recentes?pagina=1000, the code will loop and keep going backwards. Now it's on page 1000, then go to all xpath and go to 999 and that's it. It will loop everything from     

> for element in transactionElements: 

I just didn't add the while loop yet.

Comment: noooo, it's the only thing I need.

Comment: thank you a loooooot for your patience lol

Comment: I posted an answer, please check, and tell me if it works fine for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see you did not import some classes and also I made some changes to your code.

```
#import libraries
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium import webdriver
import os
import time

# set options for web driver
option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_prefs = {}
option.experimental_options["prefs"] = chrome_prefs
chrome_prefs["profile.default_content_settings"] = {"images": 2}
chrome_prefs["profile.managed_default_content_settings"] = {"images": 2}
chrome_prefs["profile.default_content_settings"] = { "popups": 2 }
option.add_argument("--disable-notifications")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=option)
driver.get('https://www.spiritfanfiction.com/login')

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='Usuario']").send_keys("breakfast")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@title='Senha']").send_keys("302290679")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='btn btn-primary']").send_keys("302290679")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='btn btn-primary']").click()

LinkDoPerfil = driver.get("https://www.spiritfanfiction.com/recentes?pagina=1000")
transactionElements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@class='usuario usuarioPopupTrigger link']")
for element in transactionElements:
            ActionChains(driver) \
                .key_down(Keys.CONTROL) \
                .click(element) \
                .key_up(Keys.CONTROL) \
                .perform()

# Store all the tabs in the variable
tabs = driver.window_handles
# Switch to each tab opened one by one
for x in tabs[1:]:
    time.sleep(2)
    driver.switch_to_window(x)
    '''
    Do whatever you want in each tab here
    '''
```

inside the for loop visit each tab and do what you want, add the code that you want the driver to perform. Please comment if you have trouble understanding any part of code.

Comment: Thank you very much. But I'm facing another problem with this code. Do you have any ideas? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55783870/how-can-i-loop-a-code-throughout-multiple-tabs